# Static ListView for options

Tags: android, listview

I want to achieve this list:

[image]

Which is basically a static list with options the user can click on. Is there a way to achieve this statically, with a XML or something like that? Somehow doing the regular listview procedure - adapter, list of items with model object - seems odd to me.

Comment: you can add horizontal line in between text and image layouts to achieve listview like look.

Answer (score 0):

If this list is always the same, it's basically just four stacked, static buttons.

You could then just use a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and place the buttons inside of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```